# How to call the function that yields (python 2.7)

Tags: python, yield

I have two functions func1 and func2 that are specific implementations of func0 that YIELDS its result:

```
def func0(parameter, **kwargs):
    #do sth with kwargs and parameter
    yield result # result is html
```

how should I refer to func0 inside the "specific" functions to make them yield their results? Is return ok?

```
def func1(**kwargs):
    return func0(parameter=1, **kwargs)

def func2(**kwargs):
    return func0(parameter=2, **kwargs)
```

Comment: If you use `return`, then `func1` will return the generator that is `func0`; if you use `yield from`, then it will yield the individual items from `func0`. The result seems to be the same in both cases.

Comment: Take a look at `partial` (https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html). It creates an instance of a function with some of the required parameters already set.

Comment: @tobias_k I suggested `yield from` but then I noticed OP was asking about Python 2 specifically. `yield from` was introduced in Python 3.3

Comment: BTW, any particular reason you are using `yield` in the first place instead of `return` for returning a single result? Seems a bit unusual to me.

Comment: yes, I am yielding html to be able to redirect after the html content has been displayed. I've used this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33788909/doing-auto-redirect-using-cherrypy

Comment: thank you for all the answers, using return has done the trick!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `return`, then `func1` will return the generator that is `func0`. Alternatively, if you use `yield from`, then the wrapping function becomes a generator itself, yielding the individual items from `func0`. The yielded elements are the same in both cases.

```
def func1(**kwargs):
    return func0(parameter=1, **kwargs)

def func2(**kwargs):
    yield from func0(parameter=1, **kwargs)
```

Note how `func1` returns a `func0`-generator, while `func2` returns a `func2`-generator.

```
>>> func1()
<generator object func0 at 0x7fe038147ea0>
>>> func2()
<generator object func2 at 0x7fe038147ee8>
>>> list(func1()) == list(func2())
True
```

Note that `yield from` was introduced in Python 3. In Python 2, you can achieve the samy by yielding from a loop.

```
def func2(**kwargs):
    for x in func0(parameter=1, **kwargs):
        yield x
```

Comment: If there's anything wrong about my answer, please drop a comment so I can fix it.

Answer (score 4):

In Python 3.3+, the normal way would be to use `yield from`. From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-380):

> PEP 380 adds the yield from expression, allowing a generator to delegate part of its operations to another generator. This allows a section of code containing yield to be factored out and placed in another generator. Additionally, the subgenerator is allowed to return with a value, and the value is made available to the delegating generator.

For Python 2.7 that's not possible, however. Here's an alternative that works instead:

```
def base_squared_generator(parameter):
    yield parameter ** 2


def two_squared_generator():
    yield next(base_squared_generator(parameter=2))


def three_squared_generator():
    yield next(base_squared_generator(parameter=3))


print(next(two_squared_generator()))
print(next(three_squared_generator()))
```

**Output**

```
4
9
```

Answer (score 1):

You are returning generators from the functions.
You need to read about generator, it's not long, anyway is here a way to use it:

```
gen = func1(args...)
res = gen.next()  # python 2
```

or 
    res = next(gen)  # python 2 and 3

Answer (score 1):

This is how i would do it:

```
def func0(a):
    yield a**2

from functools import partial

func1 = partial(func0, a=1)
func2 = partial(func0, a=10)
print(next(func1()))  # prints 1
print(next(func2()))  # prints 100
```

You can take a look at [`partial`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) there. As i said in the comments it essentially clones your function with some of its required parameters already set.

---

So if `func0` *yields* so do its partials `func1` and `func2`.

Comment: thanks for this answer. Unfortunately I cannot accept multiple answers but I've upvoted yours

Comment: Just go with whatever works for you best. This proved to be an XY problem; you didn't need `yield` to begin with.